# Vagrant, enable key-less SSH login

Tags: ssh, key, vagrant, ansible

I have a vagrant VM that I'm configuring using ansible.  In my provisioning script, I'm creating a user and setting their password, but I suspect the password is being hashed somehow into something I can't use:

```
    - name: Create SSH user for workers
      action: user name=worker password=worker shell=/bin/bash groups=vagrant
```

When I go `ssh worker@myvmhost` and enter the password `worker` I get the message:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Is there any way I can set up a user on my vagrant box that can simply log in using a username and password?  In this case `worker`/`worker`.

Answer (score 1):

You're write in saying that the [password is hashed](http://docs.ansible.com/user_module.html).

There is a guide [here](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) for setting a password for a user.

In short it's done like this:

```
pip install passlib
python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('worker')"
```

And then use the value in your playbook. If you want it to be fully automated you can do something like:

```
- name: ensure passlib python lib is installed
  pip: name=passlib
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: hash password
  shell: python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('worker')"
  register: hashed_pw
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: create SSH user for workers
  user: name=worker
        password={{ hashed_pw.stdout }}
        shell=/bin/bash
        groups=vagrant
```

Note that using this method the password will be hashed on your *host machine and not the remote*.